# Angular2 routing redirects to wrong url

Tags: .htaccess, angular2-routing

I have an angular2 application in a subfolder `/draft` on a apache server.
In order to get it working I added this `.htaccess` in /draft:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /draft/index.html [L]
```

And added this to `/draft/index.html` in the head:

```html
<base href="draft/">
```

My components and other typescript files are in /draft/app/,
and my `/draft/systemjs.config.js` looks like this:

```js
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': '/draft/node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      app: '/draft/app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      // ...
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

This all works fine, but when I try to add routing something goes wrong.
When the user goes to `/draft/foo`, I want the component FooComponent to be shown.
But when the user goes to `/draft/foo`, the FooComponent is shown as expected, but for some reason the url is changed to `/draft/draft/draft/foo`.

This is my `/draft/app/app.routing.js`:

```js
// ...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'draft/foo',
        component: FooComponent
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I added the routing const to the imports array of my AppModule, `/draft/app/app.module.ts`:

```js
// ...
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, FooComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`/draft/app/components/AppComponent.ts` looks like this:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

So why is `/draft/foo` redirected to `/draft/draft/draft/foo` and what can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the base was incorrect.
With the following base everything works.

```
<base href="http://localhost/draft/" />
```

To make it more dynamic I replaced it with this:

```js
<script>
  document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
```

But this only works when using the `hash location strategy` because otherwise the Route path is always ' '. So I ended up using the following:

```js
<script>
  document.write('<base href="' + document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host + '/draft/' + '" />');
</script>
```